# Does racket plt have an equivalent to Python's sha1.update()

Tags: racket, sha

I'd like to hash stdin in chunks using racket but can't find an equivalent to Python's hashlib's sha1.update function is there an equivalent or alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#lang racket
(require (planet soegaard/digest:1:2/digest))

(define a #"The quick brown fox jumps ")
(define b #"over the lazy dog")
(define a+b (bytes-append a b))

(digest a+b 'sha1)

(define c (make-digest-context 'sha1))
(update-context c a)
(update-context c b)
(final-context->hex-string c)
```

The output is:

```
"2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12"
"2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12"
```

You can find documentation on the `digest` collection here:
http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/soegaard/digest.plt/1/2/doc.txt

Use it something like this:

```
(define c (make-digest-context 'sha1))
(define in (open-input-file "foo"))
(let loop ()
  (define chunk (read-bytes 4096 in))
  (cond [(eof-object? chunk) (final-context->hex-string c)]
        [else                (update-context c chunk)
                             (loop)]))
```

Comment: Doesn't this require me to keep all the previously read bytes in memory? If I'm reading a file gigabytes in size this would not be practical, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: No, the context doesn't store the input bytes. It uses very little internal state. See the added example.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Greg Hendershott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343414/greg-hendershott)'s [`sha`](https://github.com/greghendershott/sha) library, which adds Racket support for SHA-1 and SHA-2 by providing a Racket interface to the OpenSSL implementation of SHA-1 and SHA-2.

```
(require sha)

(sha1 bstr) -> sha1?    
  bstr : bytes?
```

Although it doesn't have an `update()` procedure, as stated in Python's own [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update) a call like this:

```
m.update(a); m.update(b)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
m.update(a+b)
```